# How to rename XML node name in a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have on my database a table with one column storing XML data. Due to changes in the source code we want to rename one specific XML node name and XML namespace. Lets say that I have the XML bellow:

```
<MediaClass xmlns="MediaClass/1">   
    <Media>
        <Title>Test</Title>
        <Type>Book</Type>
        <Price>1.00</Price>
    </Media>
</MediaClass>
```

How can I rename the Node **MediaClass** name to let's say **Book** and also change the namespace value?

So it can look like as:

```
<Book xmlns="Book/1">   
    <Media>
        <Title>Test</Title>
        <Type>Book</Type>
        <Price>1.00</Price>
    </Media>
</Book>
```

I need to do it entirely in T-SQL as this will be used as a migration script. The minimum SQL Server installed on ours customers is SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible with [XML DML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177454.aspx)

It might work for you to use [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) instead.

```
update YourTable set
  XMLCol = replace(replace(cast(XMLCol as nvarchar(max)), 
                           '<MediaClass xmlns="MediaClass/1">', 
                           '<Book xmlns="Book/1">'), 
                   '</MediaClass>', 
                   '</Book>')
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my first approach indeed, but because my XML are bigger than 8000 characters, I have to use more complicated solution (http://www.sqlteam.com/article/search-and-replace-in-a-text-column) which I want to avoid.

Comment: @Andres - That is not a problem when you cast to `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: Yeah, after trying and guessing I think this is the most possible and feasible approach now. Thanks

Comment: Amazing... this helped a lot! :)