# how to modify xml node in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an xml column in my table named 'Content_Html' in which the data would look like:

```
 <root>
      <Category>Cover Impression</Category>
      <Title>Mystery of the Wolves</Title>
      <Month>April</Month>
      ...
      ...
    </root>
```

I am trying to replace the element under `<Category>` from Cover Impression to Cover Impressions, and after the replace, my table with this category should look like

```
<Category>Cover Impressions</Category>
```

I checked this article (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316712/how-to-rename-xml-node-name-in-a-sql-server) for my question, but not exactly what i am looking for.

Can some one point me in the right direction ?

after suggestions down below i tried this:

```
declare @newValue XML
select @newValue = 'Cover Impressions'
update dbo.content 
set content_html.modify('replace value of (/root/Category/text())[1] with sql:variable("@newValue")')
```

but giving me "Cannot call methods on ntext" error
Thanks,

Comment: Well duh - if your column is of type `NTEXT`, of course the XML functions won't work! I just assumed it was an XML column (since you **said so!**) First of all: **don't use NTEXT** anymore - it's deprecated - if at all, use `nvarchar(max)` and if it's a column containing XML - **USE** `XML` ...

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this..

for this code ..

```
    <Sample>
  <NodeOne>Value1</NodeOne>
  <NodeTwo>Value2</NodeTwo>
  <NodeThree>OldValue</NodeThree>
</Sample>
```

to replace ‘OldValue’ in NodeThree with ‘NewValue’.

```
 DECLARE @newValue varchar(50)
 SELECT @newValue = 'NewValue'

 UPDATE [Product]
 SET ProductXml.modify('replace value of (/Sample/NodeThree/text())[1] with sql:variable("@newValue")')
```

pls go through this for [more information](http://whyiamright.wordpress.com/2008/01/02/updating-xml-column-in-sql-server-2005/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i am getting "Cannot call methods on ntext" error message when i execute this statement.

Comment: @ marc_s thanks for your feedback, i am not proficient in sql - anyhow, i tried your method of declaring my variable as XML and still getting the same message - "Cannot call methods on ntext"...

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** What you could try (but **please** - on a **TEST** environment first!) is to just simply change the datatype of your column to XML:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
  ALTER COLUMN Content_Html XML
```

If you have only valid XML content in all your rows for that column, this command ought to work.

Once that has worked - then you can try this for your specific example :

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Content_Html.modify('replace value of (/root/Category/text())[1] with "Cover Impressions"')
WHERE ...(whatever condition need here).....
```

Comment: Well duh - if your column is of type `NTEXT`, of course the XML functions won't work! I just assumed it was an XML column (since you **said so!**) First of all: **don't use NTEXT** anymore - it's deprecated - if at all, use `nvarchar(max)` and if it's a column containing XML - **USE** `XML` ...