# Moving nodes in XML and rename them using XML DML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml-dml

Given the following XML all nodes named **IsEurozone** have to be renamed to **HasFxrEuro**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MacroScenarios>
  <MacroScenario>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Macro Scenario 1</Name>
    <Scenarios>
      <Scenario>
        <CountryIsoAlpha3>USA</CountryIsoAlpha3>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <IsEurozone>true</IsEurozone>
      </Scenario>
      <Scenario>
        <CountryIsoAlpha3>GER</CountryIsoAlpha3>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <IsEurozone>true</IsEurozone>
      </Scenario>
    </Scenarios>
  </MacroScenario>
</MacroScenarios>
```

The replace-operation can easily done (thanks to Mikael Erikssons post [How to rename XML node name in a SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7317507/5835794)):

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MacroScenarioSets] set
[ContentAsXml] = 
        replace(
            replace(
                cast(ContentAsXml as nvarchar(max)), 
                '<IsEurozone>', 
                '<HasFxrEuro>'),
            '</IsEurozone>', 
            '</HasFxrEuro>')
```

After that the content of the Scenario node would look like:

```
  <Scenario>
    <CountryIsoAlpha3>USA</CountryIsoAlpha3>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <HasFxrEuro>true</HasFxrEuro>
  </Scenario>
```

But in my case I need a strict alphabetical order of the nodes and so **HasFxrEuro** must be placed before **Id**.

My idea was to do something like

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MacroScenarioSets]
SET ContentAsXml.modify('insert 
<HasFxrEuro>{(/MacroScenarios/MacroScenario/Scenarios/Scenario/IsEurozone/text())}</HasFxrEuro>
after (/MacroScenarios/MacroScenario/Scenarios/Scenario/CountryIsoAlpha3)')
```

and after that delete all old **IsEurozone** nodes. But XML DML requires a singleton for insert-statements. Is there another way to achieve that with XML DML?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? From 2014 there is the `replace value of` XML DML. I think this could help you. More information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx

Comment: It is SQL Server 2012 SP 3. And from what I understand 'replace value of' replaces the value of a node, not the name. And it does not move the node in the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I got it running by manually walking through the XML document:

```
    declare @scenarioCursor int = 1
    declare @macroScenarioCursor int = 1

    while 1 = 1
    begin

            -- Add HasFxrEuro with the value of IsEurozone
           UPDATE @myxml
           SET content.modify('
               insert 
                <HasFxrEuro>{(/MacroScenarios/MacroScenario[sql:variable("@macroScenarioCursor")]/Scenarios/Scenario[sql:variable("@scenarioCursor")]/IsEurozone[1]/text())}</HasFxrEuro>
               after ((/MacroScenarios/MacroScenario[sql:variable("@macroScenarioCursor")]/Scenarios/Scenario[sql:variable("@scenarioCursor")]/CountryIsoAlpha3))[1]')
           WHERE content.exist('
                (/MacroScenarioSet/MacroScenarios/MacroScenario[sql:variable("@macroScenarioCursor")]/Scenarios/Scenario[sql:variable("@scenarioCursor")])') = 1

           if @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
           begin
                -- the end
                if @scenarioCursor = 1
                    break;
                else
                    -- increment cursor over MacroScenario, reset cursor over Scenario
                   begin
                         SET @macroScenarioCursor = @macroScenarioCursor + 1
                         SET @scenarioCursor = 1
                   end 
            end       
            else
                begin

                    -- HasFxrEuro has been added remove IsEurozone
                    UPDATE @myxml
                    SET content.modify('
                        delete (/MacroScenarios/MacroScenario[sql:variable("@macroScenarioCursor")]/Scenarios/Scenario[sql:variable("@scenarioCursor")]/IsEurozone)')

                    -- increment Scenario cursor
                    SET @scenarioCursor = @scenarioCursor + 1
               end

end
```

The solution is very slow. But I have no other idea how to solve this in SQL.